# Copy .dylib library from one xcode project to another

Tags: xcode, compilation, linker, shared-libraries, dylib

So I have one Xcode project that I downloaded that comes with a ~.dylib file and a folder titled 'include' that comes with all the files for that library.

What I want to do is copy these files into another XCode project.

However I don't know how to get XCode to recognize the ~.dylib file. Right now XCode allows me to create instances of classes defined in this library but whenever I try to call any associated methods it says it can't find those methods and gives an error (presumably because the ~.dylib file is not linked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Select your project file, choose your target, Build Settings, and search for "Library Search Paths", and add the path to your dylib file to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this suggestion however I am unfortunately still getting the same error =(

Comment: actually what dylib you are trying to use?

Comment: libassimp.dylib for open asset import library

Comment: oops sorry I mixed up linking static libraries and dynamic libraries. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still having issues. Should the dylib file be in the same directory as my xcode project or should I add it to the frameworks folder in my harddrive?